# The Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Let P be a non zero projector. Is ($||P||_F\geq 1$ with equality if and only if P is an orthogonal projector) true?

My question is about the the Frobenius norm of P, is this true $||P||_F\geq 1$ with equality if and only if P is an orthogonal projector.
I know it is happen in $2$-norm.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P^2=P\ne0$, we have $\|P\|_F=\|P^2\|_F\le\|P\|_F^2$ and hence $\|P\|_F\ge1$.

If $\|P\|_F=1$, then $1=\|P\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_i\sigma_i(P)^2}\ge\sigma_1(P)\ge\rho(P)=1$. Therefore the only nonzero singular value of $P$ is equal to $1$, meaning that $P=uv^\ast$ for some unit vectors $u$ and $v$. Since $P^2=P$, we must have $v^\ast u=1$. Therefore $u=v$ and $P=uu^\ast$ is a rank-one orthogonal projector.